# Using the Switch case statment

Tags: c

I'm using a switch case here to get the monthly salary and month, follow the month the user will enter his salary will *change*.

After I enter a salary once, then I enter the month. Thereafter, it is asking me to enter a number again, probably the month that is in the case. What am I doing wrong?

```
float sal;
int month;

printf("Enter your salary& month");
scanf("%f %d\n",&sal, &month);


switch (month)
{
```

thanks.

Comment: incomplete question...

Comment: Try change to get 1 user input with each scanf, in your case, 1 for sal, another for month.

Comment: Input the Salary, then space, input the month and then press Enter key

Comment: What has this to do with a switch statement?

Answer (score 1):

---

from scanf statement :

```
scanf("%f %d\n",&sal, &month);
```

Remove `'\n'`, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the newline in the scanf(), then it should work.

```
scanf("%f %d",&sal, &month);
```